# Computing complex polynom value

Tags: haskell, complex-numbers, hugs

I want to compute value of a complex polynomial at the given point, in haskell.

Polynomial is given as a list of `((Int,Int),Int)` elements, where the pair `(Int,Int)` stands for real and imaginary unit of the quotient, and the remaining `Int` represents degree. Therefore, value of the polynomial in complex point `x` is computed as the sum of `a_i*(x^t)` where `a_i` is the `i`th quotient and `t` degree.

Here is my `haskell` code:

```
type Komp = (Int, Int)
(+%) :: Komp -> Komp -> Komp
(r1, i1) +% (r2, i2)    = (r1+r2, i1+i2)

(*%) :: Komp -> Komp -> Komp
(r1, i1) *% (r2, i2)    = (r1*r2 - i1*i2, r1*i2 + i1*r2)

(^%) :: Komp -> Int -> Komp
k ^% 1      = k
k ^% n      = (k ^% (n-1)) *% k

vredKompPol :: [(Komp,Int)] -> Komp -> Komp
vredKompPol ((k,s):poli) t  = k*%(t^%s) +% (vredKompPol poli t)
```

`+%`, `*%` and `^%` are nothing more but operations `+`, `*` and `^` defined over complex numbers represented by the type `Komp`.

It loads fine with hugs, but execution:

```
Main> vredKompPol [((1,1),2),((1,1),0)] (0,0)
```

throws an error:

`ERROR - Control Stack Overflow`

which I don't know why it happens or how to debug it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are at least two bugs I spot. The one causing your problem is that your base case for `(^%)` is too high, so

```
> (1,1) ^% 0
*** Exception: stack overflow
```

Fix it by changing the base case to

```
k ^% 0 = (1, 0)
```

The second is that you have no base case for `vredKompPol`, which you can fix by adding a clause like

```
vredKompPol [] _ = (0, 0)
```

With these two changes, I get:

```
*Main> vredKompPol [((1,1),2),((1,1),0)] (0,0)
(1,1)
```

That looks right to me.

Comment: Thanks, Daniel, after those bugs were fixed program works just fine. :)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your implementation of `%^` is only defined for `n >= 1`, but you're trying to use it with `n = 0`, which never reaches the base case (`n = 1`).

Now, hugs is out of development so I would recommend using ghci instead. In ghci, you can debug similar problems like this:

```
[jakob:~]$ ghci foo.hs
GHCi, version 7.8.4: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( foo.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Main.
```

Set a flag to enable breaking on Ctrl-c:

```
*Main> :set -fbreak-on-error
```

Trace the problematic function:

```
*Main> :trace vredKompPol [((1,1),2),((1,1),0)] (0,0)
```

After a little while, press Ctrl-c to stop execution.

```
^CStopped at <exception thrown>
_exception :: e = _
```

`:history` shows the execution history.

```
[<exception thrown>] *Main> :history
-1  : *% (foo.hs:6:1-56)
-2  : ^% (foo.hs:10:15-31)
-3  : ^% (foo.hs:10:22-24)
-4  : ^% (foo.hs:(9,1)-(10,31))
-5  : ^% (foo.hs:10:16-25)
-6  : *% (foo.hs:6:1-56)
-7  : ^% (foo.hs:10:15-31)
-8  : ^% (foo.hs:10:22-24)
-9  : ^% (foo.hs:(9,1)-(10,31))
-10 : ^% (foo.hs:10:16-25)
-11 : *% (foo.hs:6:1-56)
-12 : ^% (foo.hs:10:15-31)
-13 : ^% (foo.hs:10:22-24)
-14 : ^% (foo.hs:(9,1)-(10,31))
-15 : ^% (foo.hs:10:16-25)
-16 : *% (foo.hs:6:1-56)
-17 : ^% (foo.hs:10:15-31)
-18 : ^% (foo.hs:10:22-24)
-19 : ^% (foo.hs:(9,1)-(10,31))
-20 : ^% (foo.hs:10:16-25)
...
```

Use `:back` to move up the execution history in order to inspect the arguments using `:show bindings`:

```
[<exception thrown>] *Main> :back
Logged breakpoint at foo.hs:6:1-56
_result :: Komp
[-1: foo.hs:6:1-56] *Main> :show bindings
_exception :: e = _
_result :: Komp = _
```

Nothing interesting here (probably because it's the function that was executing when Ctrl-c was pressed). Move up a step and try again:

```
[-1: foo.hs:6:1-56] *Main> :back
Logged breakpoint at foo.hs:10:15-31
_result :: Komp
k :: Komp
n :: Int
[-2: foo.hs:10:15-31] *Main> :show bindings
_exception :: e = _
n :: Int = -12390
k :: Komp = (0,0)
_result :: Komp = _
[-2: foo.hs:10:15-31] *Main>
```

So, it's executing on line 10 with `n = -12390`. This suggests a problem with non-terminating recursion.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and for the tip about ghci, I'll switch to it eventually, but for now I have to deal with hugs.